# How do i change multiple references at once in Java?

Tags: java, performance, reference, complexity-theory

I have an array holding references for objects. I want to change some of those references in the array to another object. At the moment I use a for loop like the one below:

```
for (int i = region2.getStartPos(); i <= curPos; i++) {        
    if (regions[i] == region2) {
        regions[i] = region1;
    }
}
```

I want to avoid the for loop though, because it increases the computational complexity.

Is there a way to make the object referenced by `region2` equal to the one of `region1` directly?
For example, I have tried writing a method in the `Region` class like the one below, but it gives me a "cannot assign a value to final variable this" error.

```
public void mergeRegions(Region region){
    this = region;
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: When you say it increases your "algorithm complexity", do you mean that it's making your code hard to read, or that it's increasing the algorithmic complexity from say O(n) to O(n^2)?

Comment: I don't care if a solution is hard to read. I mean complexity like O(n) to O(n^2).

Comment: OK. If you say "algorithmic complexity" (with an "ic") or "computational complexity", it's more clear than the generic phrase "algorithm complexity". Stack Overflow tags can help here too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.. I didn't mean to be unclear.

Comment: :) It's okay; this comment area is meant to be used for clarifying questions.

Answer (score 1):

Each reference in Java is simply an address to some object in memory, so the kind of "automatic updates" you're asking for require aren't possible without some extra code.

Imagine that `region1` references the address `0x1001` in memory, and `region2` references `0x2001`. These two memory locations hold the actual region data:

- **`0x1001`**: `x = 0, y = 5, width = 20, height = 30`
- **`0x2001`**: `x = 100, y = 200, width = 50, height = 20`

If you could somehow tell the object at `0x2001` to be equal to `0x1001`, using your `mergeRegions` method, would Java try to do something like this?

- **`0x1001`**: `x = 0, y = 5, width = 20, height = 30`
- **`0x2001`**: `0x1001`

This wouldn't work though, because the Java objects are both supposed to be `Region` objects, each with the same fields and methods. If we wipe out the the Java object at `0x2001`, and just put in a plain address, none of the existing references to `0x2001` would work, because they're all expecting a `Region` object at that address. That's why you cannot "directly assign" one Java reference to another.

Here are three hints to help you redesign your algorithm:

1. Instead of copying the address `0x1001` into `0x2001`, you can copy all of the data from `0x1001` into the object at `0x2001`. This would make both objects equivalent, but separate.
2. You can introduce one level of indirection. If you know C, think "pointers to pointers". Your `regions` array would hold a references to `IndirectRegion` objects, which would in turn hold references to the actual `Region` objects. When you want to update `region2` to `region1`, you only need to ask one of the `IndirectRegion` objects to update its internal reference.
3. Wait until the end of your algorithm before you merge the regions. If you're able to collect up all the merge operations, you may be able to execute all of them in a single O(n) loop.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment is very insightful.. I will give the first and third hind some thought to see what i can achieve.. I am not sure though if the first will help me because after merging I need the two regions to act as one and all changes made to one, to apply on both of them. As for the second one, if I understand it correctly.. I have already thought of it and implemented it. It comes to the same situation where I have to search all IndirectRegions to find the ones that contain the region i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because it will break the contract of how that object might behave to other callers. Your first for-loop is the best you can do. A better solution might be to not use an array and instead use something that has O(1) access. For example, a `Set<T>`. You could something like

```
set.remove(region2);
set.add(region1);
```

Which will be really fast if you have written, `.equals()` and `.hashcode()`

Another solution is to copy everything from one class to another. I am not sure how I feel about this and if it is even safe. But you can do something like.

```
public void mergeRegions(Region region){
    this.a=region.a;
    this.b=region.b;
    this.c=region.c;
    this.d=region.d;
}
```

Comment: I thought it might not be possible. Thanks for the suggestions. I will try something like the first one and see if it at least decreases the run time. The second one I cannot apply in what i am trying to do.

Comment: @ynot glad I can help. Give a status update on what you did. And don't forget to accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

What are you using the array for? Amir's and Dan's suggestions about swapping the contents or using an indirection came to my mind, too. But I have the feeling that maybe you should change your data structure. So could you please elaborate on the usage of your array?

For instance, if you just have a few regions, n, then maybe instead of using an array of region-objects, you could use n sets of integers and use set operations like union, intersection and complement, or swapping sets. Or you don't even need the integers any more, but could use EnumSets or EnumMaps.

If you happen to have Josh Bloch's book "Effective Java", take a look at Item 25 about arrays and Item 32/33 about EnumSets/EnumMaps.

Comment: I am implementing some image segmentation methods and the regions represent segments of the image. I use the regions array to store the regions each pixel belongs to. It wasn't really necessary to use another data structure up until now but I will definitely try to see how others will behave. Thanks for the book recommendation. I never happened to read it but i will have a look at it now and see if it helps.

Comment: Ok, so it seems you have a one-dimensional array for the bits, and regions that also encode the bits via private int startPos, so actually some redundancy. How about avoiding the array, starting with a list of regions, each containing:  startPos == its pixel's int value (x-coordinate or so),

Comment: an end-position and a pointer to the next region. That way you no longer have redundancy and can join regions in O(1). If that's not possible, I'd use the suggested indirection. But you can still read the very fine book from Josh Bloch ;)